# Парсинг JSON-ответа с помощью Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, вконтакте

Требуется  из JSON ответа получить  несколько значений, пример:

```
{"response":{"count":1158,"unread_dialogs":5,"items":[{"unread":247,"message":{"id":606897,"date":1441637552,"out":0,"user_id":261238234,"read_state":0,"title":"Вова, не трогай котикаф","body":"рип ангел","chat_id":60,"chat_active":[143932243,67463579,89780064,156305972,219100799,279883080,278401247,63978237,236548043,18128006,172913248,223386494,151548290,274091233,275731093,261238234,272130632,215948747,115902960,179462619,310321856,309337547,132601651,73369298,197484075,56490870,314949237,145607814,230888230,127010641,97159873,227957341,316944318,267394592,296070568,158701794,307575713,302530258,274043557,262464688,322229680],"push_settings":{"sound":0,"disabled_until":-1},"users_count":43,"admin_id":143932243,"photo_50":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c623723\/v623723341\/3d431\/1eHfQXrtN68.jpg","photo_100":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c623723\/v623723341\/3d430\/g6mdJ3OiSi4.jpg","photo_200":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c623723\/v623723341\/3d42f\/0hfcii-i9sM.jpg"}},{"unread":288,"message":{"id":606850,"date":1441637232,"out":0,"user_id":243834389,"read_state":0,"title":"Песат какойта","body":"","attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":380631736,"album_id":-3,"owner_id":243834389,"photo_75":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622426\/v622426389\/3fa70\/iSW5omEuCU8.jpg","photo_130":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622426\/v622426389\/3fa71\/hJDwVmDYEtY.jpg","photo_604":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622426\/v622426389\/3fa72\/5sMHgSgrAfY.jpg","width":296,"height":99,"text":"","date":1441637232,"access_key":"297004d56320bc2227"}}],"chat_id":75,"chat_active":[156305972,278401247,219100799,272130632,223386494,158701794,276539367,172913248,279883080,89780064,155160916,55475785,67788426,279508895,306789926,243834389,135789959,288352317,270312149,274091233,90735275],"push_settings":{"sound":0,"disabled_until":-1},"users_count":22,"admin_id":156305972,"photo_50":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622126\/v622126972\/4d4c7\/0W-ma1zZ3w4.jpg","photo_100":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622126\/v622126972\/4d4c6\/CYKgzWjXf04.jpg","photo_200":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c622126\/v622126972\/4d4c4\/TXjRF68B0jI.jpg"}},{"message":{"id":606737,"date":1441633270,"out":0,"user_id":206579645,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"Попробуй еще"}},{"message":{"id":606731,"date":1441633098,"out":1,"user_id":158021141,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"В полную сили били?"}},{"message":{"id":606720,"date":1441632727,"out":1,"user_id":190661725,"read_state":0,"title":" ... ","body":"Не , завтра приду , надо документы забрать"}}]}}
```

Мне нужно получить отсюда значения `user_id` или `chat_id`, `body` и записать их в массив.

Единственное что я смог написать это:

```
public class PushSettings
{
    public int sound { get; set; }
    public int disabled_until { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int album_id { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public string photo_75 { get; set; }
    public string photo_130 { get; set; }
    public string photo_604 { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public string access_key { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Photo photo { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int @out { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int read_state { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public int chat_id { get; set; }
    public List<int> chat_active { get; set; }
    public PushSettings push_settings { get; set; }
    public int users_count { get; set; }
    public int admin_id { get; set; }
    public string photo_50 { get; set; }
    public string photo_100 { get; set; }
    public string photo_200 { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int unread { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int unread_dialogs { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну насчёт "написать" вы погорячились :) Этот код явно сгенерирован.

```
var rootobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        var items = rootobj.response.items;
        var myObj = items.Select(x => new { UserId = x.message.user_id, ChatId = x.message.chat_id, Body = x.message.body });
```

Comment: Извините за тупость, ибо я совсем зелёный.
http://prntscr.com/8dpbyg - но не знаю как решить проблему ;C

Comment: @nikitas21 добавь в то же пространство имён сгенерированные классы, или добавь их пространства имён в using в верху файла